# sigrok-cli does not pipe correctly into a C# program

Tags: python, c#, pipe

So, I'm trying to take output from sigrok-cli, and pipe it into a program that then writes it to a serial port as a binary stream. I'm using C# to rapid-prototype.

```
while (true)
            {
                if (Console.In.Peek() !=-1)
               
                {
                    char b = (char)Console.Read();
                    if (b == -1)
                        continue; //redundant, I know, but I'm grasping at straws
                    if (b != '\n')
                    {
                        line += b;
                        continue;
                    }
                    ....  //process line  - doesn't require the \n, so I left it off.
                    line="";
                }
           .... //Other code
           }
```

I'm also recording timing gaps between outputs in order to determine how I batch the data.

If I pipe sigrok-cli to a file, then type (or cat under Linux) the file to my program, it works as expected. If I run it from sigrok-cli directly, it gets a couple of lines then hangs up. I've already tried Console.Readline(), and my 'custom' read line in the code above behaves the same. Neither work. Behavior is the same under mono. I tried also piping through buffer, dd, unbuffer, stdbuf (-oL) and a quite a bit of messing around with sizes. A larger buffer gets all the data, but loses the timing information. -oL doesn't seem to help at all.

Another oddity, is that most of the time if sigrok-cli is reading a file as opposed to actual hardware, it seems to work fine. It seems to be some weirdness with piping logic.

Could there be an issue in sigrok-cli where it is not flushing the buffer? Is there a way to flush the buffer from a sigrok decoder module? Any ideas what else I could try?

(I've tagged this python, as I can't tag sigrok)